# Mocked suspend function returns null in Mockito

Tags: junit, kotlin, mockito, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a suspending functions that I have mocked, using Mockito but it is returning null

both projects use

```
'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0'
```

Example 1

here is my test in which the mock is returning null

```
@Test
fun `when gps not enabled observer is notified`() = runBlocking {
    // arrange
    `when`(suspendingLocationService.getCurrentLocation()).thenReturn(result) // <- when called this returns null

    // act
    presenter.onStartShopButtonClick()

    // assert
    verify(view).observer
    verify(observer).onPrepareShop()
}
```

I have the below implementation in my presenter

```
  override suspend fun onStartShopButtonClick() {
    val result = suspendingLocationService.getCurrentLocation() // <- in my test result is null!!!!!!
    view?.apply {
        observer?.onPrepareShop()
        when {
            result.hasGivenPermission == false -> observer?.onStartShop(StoreData(), APIError(APIError.ErrorType.NO_PERMISSION))
            result.hasGPSEnabled == false -> observer?.onStartShop(StoreData(), APIError(APIError.ErrorType.GPS_NOT_ENABLED))
            result.latitude != null && result.longitude != null ->
                storeLocationService.getCurrentStore(result.latitude, result.longitude) { store, error ->
                    observer?.onStartShop(store, error)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

however I have what I believe to a very similar implementation that is working below

Example 2

The below test does pass and the correct the function does respond with a product

```
@Test
fun `suspending implementation updates label`() = runBlocking {
    // arrange
    `when`(suspendingProductProvider.getProduct("testString")).thenReturn(product)

    // act
    presenter.textChanged("testString")

    // assert
    verify(view).update(product.name)
}
```

here is the implementation of the presenter

```
override suspend fun textChanged(newText: String?) {
    val product = suspendingNetworkProvider.getProduct(newText)
    view?.update(product.name)
}
```

here is the interface I am mocking

```
interface SuspendingProductProvider {
    suspend fun getProduct(search: String?): Product
}
```

what I am not doing in the first example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mockito has a special support for `suspend` functions, but in Kotlin 1.3 there were some changes in how coroutines are implemented internally, so older versions of Mockito are no longer recognize `suspend` methods compiled by Kotlin 1.3. And `kotlinx.coroutines` use Kotlin 1.3 since version 1.0.0.

Corresponding support was added to Mockito, but only [since version 2.23](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/1501#issuecomment-427346252), so updating your Mockito version will help.

Comment: I'm using org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.0, and I still have this issue

Comment: Mockito 3.3.3, and same issue. @iori24 have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 10):

first get [Mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) and
in **mockito** you can use this code when you want to mock **suspend functions** :

```
        val mockedObject: TestClass = mock()
        mockedObject.stub {
            onBlocking { suspendFunction() }.doReturn(true)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mock multiple functions during initialisation. Let say, we have repository:

```kotlin
interface ContactRepository {
    suspend fun getContact(contactId: Long): Contact
    fun getContactsFlow(): Flow<List<Contact>>
}
```

You can mock both method in place:

```kotlin
val testContact = ContactModel(testId)
val repository: ContactRepository = mock {
    onBlocking { getContact(testId) } doReturn testContact
    on { getContactsFlow() } doReturnFlow flowOf(listOf(testContact))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The top answer is the correct answer. I upgraded to mockito 2.23 and was able to do this successfully, without encountering the issue of null value. I faced the same issue with mockito 2.21

```
class Parser {
suspend fun parse(responseBody: ByteArray) : Result = coroutineScope {/*etc*/}
}

val expectedResult = Mockito.mock(Result::class.java)
Mockito.`when`(mockParser.parse(byteArrayOf(0,1,2,3,4))).thenReturn(coroutineScope {
 expectedResult
})
```