# Android Coroutine MVP junit test code failed

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, coroutine, clean-architecture

I am developing a toy Android app using Kotlin (Coroutine).

I am familiar with Rx more than Coroutine.

I feel that Coroutine difficult more than Rx.

Anyway here is my Presenter code:

```
class NowPlayingPresenter(
    private val view: NowPlayingContract.View,
    private val getMovies: GetNowPlayingMovies,
    private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main,
    ioContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO
) : NowPlayingContract.Presenter, CoroutineScope, AnkoLogger {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Job() + ioContext

    override fun unsubscribe() {
        coroutineContext.cancel()
    }

    override fun getMoviesNowPlaying() {
        view.showProgressBar(View.VISIBLE)
        view.hideError()

        launch {
            try {
                val movies = getMovies.get()

                // 'movies' is always null!!! I don't know why...

                withContext(uiContext) {
                    view.showProgressBar(View.GONE)
                    if (movies.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        view.onError(R.string.err_movies_not_exists)
                    } else {
                        view.onMoviesLoaded(movies)
                    }
                }
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                view.showProgressBar(View.GONE)
                view.onError(R.string.err_get_movies_failed)
                error("[Y.M.] getMoviesNowPlaying - failed: ${t.message}", t)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my GetNowPlayingMovies code, it is just interface:

```
interface GetNowPlayingMovies {
    suspend fun get(): List<SimpleMovie>
}
```

And below is my JUnit test code:

```
class MyDataPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockView: NowPlayingContract.View

    @Mock
    private lateinit var getMovies: GetNowPlayingMovies

    private lateinit var presenter: NowPlayingPresenter

    private lateinit var inOrder: InOrder

    private val mockMovie1 = SimpleMovie("posterpath1", false, "2019-03-01", 10, "hello world1", 10f)
    private val mockMovie2 = SimpleMovie("posterpath2", true, "2019-03-02", 20, "hello world2", 9f)
    private val mockMovie3 = SimpleMovie("posterpath3", false, "2019-03-03", 30, "hello world3", 8f)
    private val mockMovie4 = SimpleMovie("posterpath4", false, "2019-03-04", 40, "hello world4", 7f)
    private val mockMovie5 = SimpleMovie("posterpath5", false, "2019-03-05", 50, "hello world5", 6f)
    private val mockMovies: List<SimpleMovie> = listOf(
        mockMovie1,
        mockMovie2,
        mockMovie3,
        mockMovie4,
        mockMovie5
    )

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mockView)

        presenter = NowPlayingPresenter(mockView, getMovies, Dispatchers.Unconfined, Dispatchers.Unconfined)
    }

    @Test
    fun getMoviesNowPlayingTest() = runBlocking {
        `when`(getMovies.get()).thenReturn(mockMovies)

        presenter.getMoviesNowPlaying()

        inOrder.verify(mockView).showProgressBar(View.VISIBLE)
        inOrder.verify(mockView).hideError()
        inOrder.verify(mockView).showProgressBar(View.GONE)
        inOrder.verify(mockView).onMoviesLoaded(mockMovies)
    }

}
```

Somebody help me, please?

Here is my full code:
https://github.com/yoonhok524/Android-Sandbox/tree/master/kotlin-coroutine

I tried to apply 'Clean architecture' in this project, so the code is not easy to read... maybe...

Comment: It would be useful if you post creating `mockData` object code.

Comment: can you share the message of the failed test?

Comment: r2rek, I already wrote the error message in the Presenter code as a comment.

Comment: Ircover, It just simple list of data class, when I check it in the test code, it was not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Mockito 1.x. If you make the mock for suspend function, use the lastest Mockito. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101077/4639261

Answer (score 0):

In my case and conventions....

1. implement 'CoroutineScope' and override coroutineContext
2. coroutineContext = Job() + Dispatchers 
   (need job.cancel() because cancel CoroutineScope and childs)
3. Use launch and withContext(...)

```html
        launch {
            val data = withContext(ioContext) { 
              repository.get(id)
            }
             
            withContext(uiContext) {
                view?.onDataLoaded(data)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I applied your code, but it failed with error message: Exception in thread "main @coroutine#1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used